# Why not make it easier to find the sites list?

Tags: feature-request

I love all these stack... sites, but there's rather a lot of them.

I've bookmarked https://stackexchange.com/sites as my starting place, but this is ridiculously difficult to find. There's a tiny link somewhere in the footers.

If users sat neatly within a particular site there would be good reason to hide this, but I find myself contributing across several and it's always a pain remembering what they're all called.

**Request: put a (css pop-up?) link at the top of all sites, along with chat, main, about...**

Answer (score 4):

Consider using the [StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66838/149668) as introduced in [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/). Click on the "Stack**Exchange**" link on the left side of the header then select "all sites":

[image: stackexchange multicollider superdropdown]

Comment: note that it is ordered by reputation on each site, provided you have 200+ on the specified site. It is in random order beyond that.

Comment: LOL. you know you're on a tech site when the response to a user feedback to make something clearer is *"it's there in a sub-tab of a menu, in random order."* ;-)

Comment: @Jeff Random order is not ideal for everyone. There have been many calls to provide better UI for this. E.g. see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115578/provide-an-option-to-sort-the-all-sites-list-on-the-stackexchange-dropdown-men

Comment: @dbjohn completely off topic re the answer you deleted today - [voting works different on Meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) Yours is a perfectly fine answer, it's a perfectly valid contribution and it would deserve to stand - even though it may get downvoted because the community consensus tends to be against customizable options

Comment: @Pekka thanks for the support. I could probably keep it but, I just don't feel like putting in the effort to defend this particular case, especially if downvoters aren't willing to discuss/share their points of view.